# What's the most "functional" way to select a subset from this array?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, c#-to-f#

I'd like to get more comfortable with functional programming, and the first educational task I've set myself is converting a program that computes audio frequencies from C# to F#. The meat of the original application is a big "for" loop that selects a subset of the values in a large array; which values are taken depends on the last accepted value and a ranked list of the values seen since then.  There are a few variables that persist between iterations to track progress toward determining the next value.

My first attempt at making this loop more "functional" involved a tail-recursive function whose arguments included the array, the result set so far, the ranked list of values recently seen, and a few other items that need to persist between executions. This seems clunky, and I don't feel like I've gained anything by turning everything that used to be a variable into a parameter on this recursive function.

How would a functional programming master approach this kind of task? Is this an exceptional situation in which a "pure" functional approach doesn't quite fit, and am I wrong for eschewing mutable variables just because I feel they reduce the "purity" of my function? Maybe they don't make it less pure since they only exist inside that function's scope. I don't have a feel for that yet.

Here's an attempted distillation of the code, with some "let" statements and the actual components of state removed ("temp" is the intermediate result array that needs to be processed):

```
let fif (_,_,_,_,fif) = fif

temp
|> Array.fold (fun (a, b, c, tentativeNextVals, acc) curVal ->
    if (hasProperty curVal c) then
        // do not consider current value
        (a, b, c, Seq.empty, acc)
    else
        if (hasOtherProperty curVal b) then
            // add current value to tentative list
            (a, b, c, tentativeNextVals.Concat [curVal], acc)
        else
            // accept a new value
            let newAcceptedVal = chooseNextVal (tentativeNextVals.Concat [curVal])

            (newC, newB, newC, Seq.empty, acc.Concat [newAcceptedVal])

) (0,0,0,Seq.empty,Seq.empty)
|> fif
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this using fold?

```
let filter list = 
    List.fold (fun statevar element -> if condition statevar then statevar else element) initialvalue list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Seq.skip and Seq.take:

```
let subset (min, max) seq =
  seq
    |> Seq.skip (min)
    |> Seq.take (max - min)
```

This function will accept arrays but return a sequence, so you can convert it back using Array.ofSeq.

PS: If your goal is to keep your program functional, the most important rule is this: avoid mutability as much as you can. This means that you probably shouldn't be using arrays; use lists which are immutable. If you're using an array for it's fast random access, go for it; just be sure to never set indices.

Comment: This question isn't about taking a block from an array